# How to set Text in Textview when Click on selected item in Listview?

Tags: android, listview

I am using Listview with ViewHolder, and setText in Textview then display error. How to setText in Textview in Listview? Whenever I click on Like Button then I get the total count for Like but I am not able to setText on TextView for every item. whenever click on selected item then Its TextView Increment by 1 Its Successfully. get strCount is Successfully but how to setText for Selected TextView when Click on Selected Image and My code is,

My Screenshot is which is Listview and set Multiple Items in Listview Like,
[image]

My Adapter Class,

```
public class Adapter1 extends BaseAdapter {

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr = null;
    Context context = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    HashMap<String, String> getData = new HashMap<String, String>();

    String url = null, urlCount = null;
    String strId = null, strCount = null;

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    public Adapter1(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arr) {

        this.context = context;
        this.arr = arr;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return arr.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return arr.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            /** initialize ViewHolder */
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            /** Initialize Widgets */
            /** Imageview */

            viewHolder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

            /** TextView */
            viewHolder.txtId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);

            viewHolder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);

            getData = arr.get(position);

            viewHolder.txtId.setText(getData.get(Fragment1.TAG_ID));

            viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                    strId = arr.get(position).get(Fragment1.TAG_ID);
                                System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!! strId======"+ strId);
                                url = "http://example.com/createpost.php?id="+ strId + "&user_id="+ myDetail.getUserId();

                    new sendData().execute();
                        }
            });

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    /** ViewHolder Class */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class ViewHolder {

        ImageView img = null, 
        TextView txtId = null
                txt = null;
    }

    public class sendData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(urlLike, ServiceHandler.GET);
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!jsonStr in Do in===" + jsonStr);
            Log.d("Response : Like", ">" + jsonStr);

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            urlCount = "http://example.com/getalldata.php?id="+ strId;
            new getCountData().execute();
        };
    }

    /** Count the Total Like for Selected Items. */
    private class getCountData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        JSONObject jsonobject;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            jsonobject = JSONFunctions.getJSONfromURL(urlCount);

            try {

                strCount = jsonobject.getString("countdata");
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!strCount====" + strCount);
            viewHolder.txt.setText(String.valueOf(strCount));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reena , post adapter code where you trying to set count please.

Comment: When you click the like button, one request to server will happen and then you will get count and then you have to show in listview right?

Comment: hey @Reena can you please attach error log here ?? as per my guess you might be getting error because you are setting text textview in doInBackground. Update your textview in onPostExecute. :)

Comment: post ur adapter and listonitemselect code.

Comment: n debug ur code n c watz happening..

Comment: @MSGadag I set the Value on Textview but Its Not Proper set for selected item in Listview.

Comment: is it getting clicked position? if not u should implement this code in activity where is ur listview declared.

Comment: @MSGadag No How to get Click Position.

Comment: @MSGadag Yes I am Make Different Adapter class not set the in activity class

Comment: pls show ur onitemselected method of ur listview. there u ll get the position.

Comment: @Reena you have to return your result to adapter class then only you can do it

Comment: `TextView txtId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtId);`   try like this. hope it works .n declare it globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onClick() function you have to get instance of textview and pass it to AsyncTask 
 
`// if text and img have same parent the you can find textview like this is 
TextView tv =(TextView)v.getParent().findViewById(R.id.txt);
// if not then apply call getParent() function multiple time as per your layout
new sendData(tv).execute();
//Create constructor in sendData
public class sendData extends AsyncTask {
   private TextView tv;
   public sendData(TextView v){
       tv=v;
   }
   ...
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            urlCount = "http://example.com/getalldata.php?id="
                    + strId;
            new getCountData(tv).execute();
        };
}
    private class getCountData extends AsyncTask {
          private TextView v;
          public sendData(TextView v){
              tv=v;
         }
       ....
       // in onPostExecute use 
       tv.setText(String.valueOf(strCount));
    }`

Edit: you can get correct position by tag position to view and get it inside onClick

```
// add this line before return 
viewHolder.img.setTag(position);
// get position inside onClick()
int position =(Integer)v.getTag();
```

Comment: in new sendData(v).execute(); pass the view and public sendData(TextView v) pass the TextView. What exactly do?